# How to understand expanded_relationships.dot

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet. At the moment I try to understand how relationsships between resources work. Because of that I looked at the graphs. Here is an example:

http://www.jansipke.nl/visualizing-puppet-manifest-resources-and-relationships/

At `expanded_relationsships.dot` I do not understand why there is one edge from `Service[ntp]` to `Class[Ntp]` and one edge the other direction. This looks like a cycle ... (And why is there an edge from `Class[Settings]` to `Class[Settings]`?)

Can some explain how dot files can be read/understand? Or maybe I missed the documentation for that and someone can post a link?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the current release of Puppet (at the time of writing 3.7.3) whichs causes the expanded relationships graph to not only contain relation edges but also containment edges. See [PUP-914](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-914) for details.

The issue will be fixed in Puppet 4.0 and there exists a [backport of the fix](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/3350) for Puppet 3.x. The easiest way to get a meaningful graph is to manually apply the fix to your local installation, the [changes](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/3350/files) are minimal.

The graph for the linked example will look as follows:

[image: expanded relations graph with fix]